# Allow user to login from one device only

Tags: android, security, authentication, token

I want to allow user to be able to login in one device only

I had this idea which is once user is logged in I will send his device token and is logged in flag.

Once he try to login using another device I will check if he's logged in in another device. If yes I will overwrite his token to the new device then I will perform log out from first device.

I don't want to prevent user from logging in from second device cause user might uninstall the app or the user phone is lost or any other case that we can't handle.

But the question is how can I perform logout from first device automatically
I don't want to send device token with all our APIs call and then check if against the saved token.

I'm not actually sure if it's doable. If it's not how can I handles cases like
uninstall app?

UPDATE

I found that snapchat use this approach they allow user to login in new device then they log him out from the old device. still not sure how they do this?

Comment: You can keep active device token in the backend whenever user login. When user tries to login using another device, you can either deny that or change active device token and logout from earlier active device token.

Comment: Imagine this scenario user is logged in in device A he uninstall the app or the device is stolen , broken , lost or whatever , then the active flag will always be true.He will try to login using device B but he won't be able to.

Comment: you don't have to send device token with all of your API calls, but only once in your  main activity onStart(), and if the response from server says that token doesn't match you just log out

Comment: But what if user is not in main activity for some amount of time and he can do some other operation that I don't want to allow him

Comment: I would also try with push notifications, once user logs in you send new token to every device of that user, the one which matches stays, others log out